# Xubuntu 20:04 (focal): IPKernelApp|Error|No such comm target registered|jupyter.widget.version

Tags: xubuntu, 20.04, python3, jupyter

I am running Xubuntu 20.04 (after upgrading from 19.04) as a guest on a VirtualBox VM in a Windows 10 host. After an `apt` install of the `jupyter` metapackage, I keep getting two errors. To reproduce them, I created a Python3 notebook with the following cells:

```
[1] import ipywidgets as widgets
[2] widgets.__version__
[3] widgets.IntSlider()
```

On running cell 1 or on re-opening the notebook the following appears in the terminal where I invoked `jupyter notebook`:

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.version
```

Cells 1 & 2 run fine. Cell 3 creates the widget and the widget seems to operate fine but the notebook and the jupyter notebook terminal show:

```
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed or enabled properly.
```

`pip3 list` (showing only relevant elements) results in:

```
jupyter-client               6.1.2         
jupyter-console              6.0.0         
jupyter-core                 4.6.3
ipykernel                    5.2.0         
ipython                      7.13.0        
ipython-genutils             0.2.0         
ipywidgets                   6.0.0
nbconvert                    5.6.1         
nbformat                     5.0.4 
notebook                     6.0.3
```

`jupyter nbextension list` shows:

```
  config dir: /home/marvin/.jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

and after I tried: `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`, the following was added:

```
  config dir: /etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

What is the best way of tracking down the problem? Or would I be better off doing one of the following:

1. re-installing via `apt`
2. re-installing via `pip3`
3. installing anaconda and re-installing via `conda`?

Many thanks

Marv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround and so am answering my own question...

I suspect the problem was that conflicting versions of `jupyter-core` were installed but I cannot prove this assertion, even when I asked the same question on [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ipywidgets/+question/690665).

My solution was to uninstall all the `pip3` and `apt` components and to delete my local configuration files. Next I installed MiniConda and created appropriate environments for my purposes using Conda. Now everything works perfectly.

(BTW: When using Conda, I recomment using separate environments for each project. If something goes wrong, it is easy to delete and start again and there seems to be less chance of conflicting binary files.)

Marv

Answer (score 1):

So, I also had the similar issues while I tried to read/write files from Spyder.
It seems to me that I didn't have enough permission to carry out a certain operation.
So, I changed the ownership of the external drives and this fixed the issues for me. The way I did it was:

```
sudo chown yourusername:yourusername /media/yourusername/path_to_mounted_volume
```

I truly hope this will solve your issue as well.